# How to use path variable instead of request parameter with AngularJS $resource

Tags: rest, resources, angularjs, path-variables

There is probably an easy way to do this but I can't seem to find out how.

When I click on my delete button shown below angular hits the following url:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/managedCourse?id=3
```

How can I get it to hit pass a path variable instead of a request parameter like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/managedCourse/3
```

Heres my html:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="course in page.content">
        <td>{{course.title}}</td>
        <td>{{course.description}}</td>
        <td>{{course.creditValue}}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="remove(course.id)">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here is my controller:

```
function ManagedCourseController($scope, $resource) 
{
    var ManagedCourse = $resource("rest/managedCourse/:courseId", {courseId:'@id'});

    $scope.page = ManagedCourse.getPage({"page.page": "0", "page.size": "3", "page.sort": "title", "page.sort.dir": "asc"});


    $scope.create = function (managedCourse) {
        ManagedCourse.create(managedCourse);
    }

    $scope.remove = function (courseId) {
        ManagedCourse.remove({id:courseId});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function ManagedCourseController($scope, $resource) 
{
    var ManagedCourse = $resource("rest/managedCourse/:courseId/:id", 
       {courseId:'@id'});
    ...
```

should do it

Comment: Will the /:id part just get ignored then? I just want to understand how that works.

Comment: Though this seems to work, I'm also wondering how this works. The [AngularJS documentation about $resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) seems not to explain this behavior. It documents about excess values are added as query parameters but not how parts of the URL template are skipped

Comment: And how would you do it for a custom action ?

Comment: I find the example above confusing. One could assume the @id is related to the second path parameter.

Comment: I successfully make use of a $resource with a path parameter without using the {courseId:'@id'} at all. And I wonder why the doc and the examples I see around all boast this.